# Kubuntu 18, 7th gen Intel graphics, incorrect max resolution

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde, intel-graphics

So I've recently switched to using KDE from Gnome on Ubuntu 18.  The System Settings >  Displays configuration will show the three displays, but will not let me activate them all at the same time unless I switch to using the Nvidia drivers (which run the fans in the notebook, which I find annoying).  This works with Ubuntu 18.04 using Gnome 3, as the Intel HD 630 supports up to 3 4k displays on DisplayPort (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025675/graphics-drivers.html).

Ubuntu 17 (Gnome) had this issue too, and it was solved with Ubuntu 18 - 7th gen Intel GPUs could have a max resolution boundary of 16384 x 16384 instead of 8192 x 8192.  I'm running the 4.17 kernel, but xrandr is still reporting a max size of 8192 x 8192.  (if I'm using the nvidia-390 drivers, it goes to 32767 x 32767).

I really like KDE 5.6 better than Gnome - everything seems to work better including display scaling on 4k displays.  But due to this apparent limitation in the software that shouldn't be there, I either have to listen to these fans or give up a display.  Anyone know of a possible fix?

Thanks!

For completeness, added the output of xrandr for both i915 and nvidia drivers:

Intel first:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 7680 x 2160, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 3840x2160+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  59.98    59.97  
   3200x1800     59.96    59.94  
   2880x1620     59.96    59.97  
   2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
   2560x1440     59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74                                                                                                              
   1024x768      60.04    60.00                                                                                                                                
   960x720       60.00                                                                                                                                         
   928x696       60.05                                                                                                                                         
   896x672       60.01                                                                                                                                         
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82                                                                                                              
   960x600       59.93    60.00                                                                                                                                
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82                                                                                                              
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25                                                                                                                       
   840x525       60.01    59.88                                                                                                                                
   864x486       59.92    59.57                                                                                                                                
   800x512       60.17                                                                                                                                         
   700x525       59.98                                                                                                                                         
   800x450       59.95    59.82                                                                                                                                
   640x512       60.02                                                                                                                                         
   720x450       59.89                                                                                                                                         
   700x450       59.96    59.88                                                                                                                                
   640x480       60.00    59.94                                                                                                                                
   720x405       59.51    58.99                                                                                                                                
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   2560x1440     59.95 +
   1280x720      59.86  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   3840x2160     24.00* 
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Nvidia driver:

```
$ xrandr    
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 10240 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
    eDP-1-1 connected primary 3840x2160+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
       3840x2160     60.00*+  59.98    59.97  
       3200x1800     59.96    59.94  
       2880x1620     59.96    59.97  
       2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
       2560x1440     59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
       2048x1536     60.00  
       1920x1440     60.00  
       1856x1392     60.01  
       1792x1344     60.01  
       2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
       1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
       1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
       1600x1200     60.00  
       1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
       1600x1024     60.17  
       1400x1050     59.98  
       1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
       1280x1024     60.02  
       1440x900      59.89  
       1400x900      59.96    59.88  
       1280x960      60.00  
       1440x810      60.00    59.97  
       1368x768      59.88    59.85  
       1360x768      59.80    59.96  
       1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
       1152x864      60.00  
       1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
       1024x768      60.04    60.00  
       960x720       60.00  
       928x696       60.05  
       896x672       60.01  
       1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
       960x600       59.93    60.00  
       960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
       800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
       840x525       60.01    59.88                                                                                                                                 
       864x486       59.92    59.57                                                                                                                                 
       800x512       60.17                                                                                                                                          
       700x525       59.98  
       800x450       59.95    59.82  
       640x512       60.02  
       720x450       59.89  
       700x450       59.96    59.88  
       640x480       60.00    59.94  
       720x405       59.51    58.99  
       684x384       59.88    59.85  
       680x384       59.80    59.96  
       640x400       59.88    59.98  
       576x432       60.06  
       640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
       512x384       60.00  
       512x288       60.00    59.92  
       480x270       59.63    59.82  
       400x300       60.32    56.34  
       432x243       59.92    59.57  
       320x240       60.05  
       360x202       59.51    59.13  
       320x180       59.84    59.32  
    DP-1-1 connected 2560x1440+7680+360 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
       2560x1440     59.95*+
       1280x720      59.86  
    HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    DP-1-2 connected 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
       3840x2160     24.00* 
       1024x768      60.00  
       800x600       60.32  
       640x480       60.00    59.94  
    HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've have this issue on Ubuntu 18.04 with an 8th gen i7 GPU (also has the HD 630).

The reason it works on Ubuntu 18.04 is because you're running GNOME on Wayland, which ignores max resolution output reported by the driver, for some reason. X on the other hand does not, and so exceeding the 8192 boundary causes the X server to bug out.

If you look at the kernel source, specifically the i915 driver, you'll notice the Intel devs stopped checking GPU versions after gen 3 (which is YEARS ago) and any GPU which isn't gen 3 or lower defaults to a max output of 8192x8192. Even though gen 6 and up (or thereabouts) all support 16384x16384.

The patch for this is laughably simple, so it's strange it hasn't been fixed. It's literally extending the if branch with an

```
/* maximum framebuffer dimensions */
if (IS_GEN2(dev_priv)) {
    dev->mode_config.max_width = 2048;
    dev->mode_config.max_height = 2048;
} else if (IS_GEN3(dev_priv)) {
    dev->mode_config.max_width = 4096;
    dev->mode_config.max_height = 4096;
} else if (IS_GEN4(dev_priv) || IS_GEN5(dev_priv)) {
    dev->mode_config.max_width = 8192;
    dev->mode_config.max_height = 8192;
} else {
    dev->mode_config.max_width = 16384;
    dev->mode_config.max_height = 16384;
}
```

For reference: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c